# Error:(41, 0) Supplied String module notation '0.12.2' is invalid

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

I am importing Eclipse project into Android studio and while importing the project getting following error:

```
Error:(41, 0) Supplied String module notation '0.12.2' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.
Open File
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':appcompat')
    compile project(':cardview')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.0'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        }

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath '0.12.2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

I am getting error on the following line:

```
classpath '0.12.2'
```

Answer (score 5):

Your script seems to be very old.

You should change the line `classpath '0.12.2'` with:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
```

I am expecting that this script should have some other issues.

- Update your Android Studio to the latest stable release (2.1)
- use `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`
- use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'`
- update the gradle version (`gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`) with `distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`